# function prepare() error en $this->Conectar() PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, function

Estoy trabajado en algunas funciones para inicios de sesión y mi clase conexión la realizo gracias al código siguiente:

```
 <?php
 class DB{
 private $host;
 private $db;
 private $user;
 private $password;
 private $charset;

 public function __construct()
 {
     $this->host = 'localhost';
     $this->db = 'dbname';
     $this->user = 'root';
     $this->password = '';
     $this->charset = 'utf8mb4';
 }
 public function Conectar(){
     try{
         $connection = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db . ";charset=" . $this->charset;

         $options = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
                     PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false];
         
         $pdo = new PDO($connection, $this->user, $this->password, $options);
     }catch(PDOException $e){
         print_r("Error connection: ". $e->getMessage());
     }
 }
```

Al crear la funcion de validación de un usuario existente tengo error en la línea `$this->Conectar()`

```
public function userExists($user, $pass){
    $md5pass = md5($pass);

    $query = $this->Conectar()->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios_del_sistema WHERE username = :user AND password = :pass');
    $query->execute(['user' => $user, 'pass' => $md5pass]);

    if($query->rowCount()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Mensaje de error**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\login.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\validate.php(20): User->userExists('prueba', 'prueba') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\includes\login.php on line 10

Comment: @BetaM ya lo hice

Comment: @BetaM debería sólo cambiar $this por $pdo en mi archivo de login? pero el de conexión permanece igual?

Comment: @BetaM Eso ha funcionado, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observaciones:

- Tu método `Conectar()` debe retornar a la conexión asignada en la variable `$pdo`, al momento la naturaleza de dicho método es `void`, solo asigna un valor pero nunca lo devuelve.

  ```
  public function Conectar()
  {
      ..................
      ..................
      return $pdo;
  }
  ```
- En este punto te recomiendo trabajar con las [declaraciones de tipo de devolución](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations) que se encuentran disponibles desde PHP 7 o superior; con lo cual podrás hacer lo siguiente:

  ```
    public function Conectar():object
    {
        ........................
        ........................
    }
  ```

Donde si no devuelve a la conexión tu método obtendrás un mensaje de error similar a este:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Return value of DB::Conectar() must be an object, none returned in

Un tanto mas descriptivo de lo que esta pasando......

Como puntos extra:

- Para hacer el *hash* de tus contraseñas no uses *md5* pues la propia documentación [no lo recomienda](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.md5.php)
- En cambio deberías pensar en opciones tales como: [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php)
- La propia documentación también indica que no debería confiarse del todo en los resultados que entrega [rowCount](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php#refsect1-pdostatement.rowcount-description) y en cambio mejor dar preferencia al uso de [fetchColumn](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)
- Además le estás asignando a la clase múltiples tareas, cuando esta debería tener asignada una y solo una cosa por hacer, ya que al momento inicializa los atributos de clase, se conecta a la base de datos y trabaja con una sentencia **`SELECT`** lo cual claramente no es le mejor camino.
- Ahora si no usas PHP 7 o superior, **pero esta dentro de tus posibilidades migrar** [recomiendo lo hagas](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)